# Unable to Make video Call in Android Lollipop 5.0 using Intents

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an application to make a video call using Intents, the code which I have tried are below,

```
   Intent callIntent = new Intent(
                                "com.android.phone.videocall");
                        callIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        callIntent.putExtra("videocall", true);
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNo));
                        startActivity(callIntent);
                        delayWait(duration);
```

But the Problem with the above code is that, working fine for all the lower versions(upto kitkat 4.4) , but it is not working in 5.0 (lollipop) version. Please suggest me some way to achieve this using Intents.

```
Error: E/com.example.menewintel.service.VideoCallService(5801): No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.phone.videocall dat=tel:xxxxxxxxx flg=0x10000000 (has extras) }
```

Comment: did you got any solution for video call intent

Answer (score 1):

Package name has been changed in lollipop

Try using this

```
"com.android.server.telecom"
```

Comment: I have tried that also . It is not coming. Thank you for your response.